# How to call the form button sitting in div?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

Below are my codes for form:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="https:example.com" method="get" name="test"> 
<div class="classy"><input type="button" class="buttonE buttonC" value="CLICK NOW"/></div>
</form>
```

I have the script below to call the button to submit, it's failed, but if I remove the div class, it can run successfully.

```
<script>
$('.buttonE').click(function(e){
$(this).parent().trigger('submit')
})
</script>
```

Could you help to provide me with the proper script to call the button which sitting in div class? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can just handle the submit event of the form directly you know. No reason to involve the button particularly (although you'd need to make it a type="submit" button as well)

Comment: The parent of the button is the div, not the form. Within the listener you could do `this.form.submit()`, but as ADyson says, just make it a submit button and put a listener on the form's submit handler (because forms can be submitted without clicking the submit button).

Comment: or simply use `$(this).closest("form").submit()`

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most simple solution I can think of.
To simply remove the `click` handler for the button and set it as the `type="submit"` for the form.

```html
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="https:example.com" method="get" name="test"> 
  <div class="classy">
    <input type="submit" class="buttonE buttonC" value="CLICK NOW"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

If you really want to use the code like you have it, then you need to use parent twice, because parent of `.buttonE` is `<div class="classy">`

```
<script>
$('.buttonE').click(function(e){
  $(this).parent().parent().trigger('submit');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set a class for form like this:

```js
$('.buttonE').click(function(e){
$(".form-app").trigger('submit')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="https:example.com" method="get" name="test" class="form-app"> 
  <div class="classy">
    <input type="button" class="buttonE buttonC" value="CLICK NOW"/>   </div>
</form>
```

**notice:** If you have already imported the JQuery library, you do not need this code line here:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```